# MVVM Commands - How to move selected item form one listbox to another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I found some great helper class for handle commands. It was found on some msdn blog.

Here is it:

```cs
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, null, false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, canExecuteMethod, false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod, bool isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
        }

        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = isAutomaticRequeryDisabled;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to determine if the command can be executed
    /// </summary>
    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (_canExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _canExecuteMethod();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Execution of the command
    /// </summary>
    public void Execute()
    {
        if (_executeMethod != null)
        {
            _executeMethod();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Property to enable or disable CommandManager's automatic requery on this command
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAutomaticRequeryDisabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled != value)
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    CommandManagerHelper.RemoveHandlersFromRequerySuggested(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
                }
                else
                {
                    CommandManagerHelper.AddHandlersToRequerySuggested(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
                }
                _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Raises the CanExecuteChaged event
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Protected virtual method to raise CanExecuteChanged event
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManagerHelper.CallWeakReferenceHandlers(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     ICommand.CanExecuteChanged implementation
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (!_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            CommandManagerHelper.AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref _canExecuteChangedHandlers, value, 2);
        }
        remove
        {
            if (!_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
            CommandManagerHelper.RemoveWeakReferenceHandler(_canExecuteChangedHandlers, value);
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Data

    private readonly Action _executeMethod = null;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecuteMethod = null;
    private bool _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = false;
    private List<WeakReference> _canExecuteChangedHandlers;

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
///     This class allows delegating the commanding logic to methods passed as parameters,
///     and enables a View to bind commands to objects that are not part of the element tree.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the parameter passed to the delegates</typeparam>
public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, null, false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, canExecuteMethod, false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod, bool isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
        }

        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = isAutomaticRequeryDisabled;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to determine if the command can be executed
    /// </summary>
    public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _canExecuteMethod(parameter);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Execution of the command
    /// </summary>
    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        if (_executeMethod != null)
        {
            _executeMethod(parameter);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Raises the CanExecuteChaged event
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Protected virtual method to raise CanExecuteChanged event
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManagerHelper.CallWeakReferenceHandlers(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Property to enable or disable CommandManager's automatic requery on this command
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAutomaticRequeryDisabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled != value)
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    CommandManagerHelper.RemoveHandlersFromRequerySuggested(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
                }
                else
                {
                    CommandManagerHelper.AddHandlersToRequerySuggested(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
                }
                _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = value;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     ICommand.CanExecuteChanged implementation
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (!_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            CommandManagerHelper.AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref _canExecuteChangedHandlers, value, 2);
        }
        remove
        {
            if (!_isAutomaticRequeryDisabled)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
            CommandManagerHelper.RemoveWeakReferenceHandler(_canExecuteChangedHandlers, value);
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // if T is of value type and the parameter is not
        // set yet, then return false if CanExecute delegate
        // exists, else return true
        if (parameter == null &&
            typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            return (_canExecuteMethod == null);
        }
        return CanExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Data

    private readonly Action<T> _executeMethod = null;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteMethod = null;
    private bool _isAutomaticRequeryDisabled = false;
    private List<WeakReference> _canExecuteChangedHandlers;

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
///     This class contains methods for the CommandManager that help avoid memory leaks by
///     using weak references.
/// </summary>
internal class CommandManagerHelper
{
    internal static void CallWeakReferenceHandlers(List<WeakReference> handlers)
    {
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            // Take a snapshot of the handlers before we call out to them since the handlers
            // could cause the array to me modified while we are reading it.

            EventHandler[] callees = new EventHandler[handlers.Count];
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = handlers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                WeakReference reference = handlers[i];
                EventHandler handler = reference.Target as EventHandler;
                if (handler == null)
                {
                    // Clean up old handlers that have been collected
                    handlers.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    callees[count] = handler;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // Call the handlers that we snapshotted
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                EventHandler handler = callees[i];
                handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void AddHandlersToRequerySuggested(List<WeakReference> handlers)
    {
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            foreach (WeakReference handlerRef in handlers)
            {
                EventHandler handler = handlerRef.Target as EventHandler;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += handler;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void RemoveHandlersFromRequerySuggested(List<WeakReference> handlers)
    {
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            foreach (WeakReference handlerRef in handlers)
            {
                EventHandler handler = handlerRef.Target as EventHandler;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= handler;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref List<WeakReference> handlers, EventHandler handler)
    {
        AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref handlers, handler, -1);
    }

    internal static void AddWeakReferenceHandler(ref List<WeakReference> handlers, EventHandler handler, int defaultListSize)
    {
        if (handlers == null)
        {
            handlers = (defaultListSize > 0 ? new List<WeakReference>(defaultListSize) : new List<WeakReference>());
        }

        handlers.Add(new WeakReference(handler));
    }

    internal static void RemoveWeakReferenceHandler(List<WeakReference> handlers, EventHandler handler)
    {
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            for (int i = handlers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                WeakReference reference = handlers[i];
                EventHandler existingHandler = reference.Target as EventHandler;
                if ((existingHandler == null) || (existingHandler == handler))
                {
                    // Clean up old handlers that have been collected
                    // in addition to the handler that is to be removed.
                    handlers.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is actually working very well when i need call void method. Here is a sample:

```cs
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        DemoHeader dd = new DemoHeader(1, "Document-1");
        dd.Items.Add(new DemoItem(1, 1, "Article 1", "A-1", 9999, "szt", ObjectType.article));
        dd.Items.Add(new DemoItem(1, 2, "Article 2", "A-2", 5999, "szt", ObjectType.article));

        this.Add(dd);
    }

    #region ICommands
    private ICommand _Run = null;
    public ICommand Run
    {
        get
        {
            return _Run ?? (new DelegateCommand(RunMethod));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CommandMethods
    public void RunMethod() //this method will be run
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```

and you need to bind it in XAML code like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Run}"/>
```

Ok, i need to pass selected listboxitem from one listbox to another. I know how to do it using event driven pattern it would be like this:

```cs
    private void Move(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if (fe.Name.Contains("da_")) //ALL DOWN
        {
           MoveSelectedItemToSourceListBox(lbArticles, lbWMSarticles);
        }
    }

    private void MoveSelectedItemToSourceListBox(ListBox source, ListBox desitination)
    {
        if (source.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            DemoItem item = source.SelectedItem as DemoItem;
            source.Items.Remove(item);
            item.AddItemToSourceList(dl); //here i'm using extension method to remove item from collection.
        }
    }
```

But how to do it using MVVM and commands, what should i do? This is really tought to achive i guess. I rly want to learn properly way od coding. Could you help me and give me dome suggestions?

Answer:

Thanks guys for help. I did not know it would be so easy. :)

Here is the answer:

You need to add in your XAML code:

```
    <ListBox Name="lbArticles" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource articles}}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ListBox>
```

In your view class you need to add:

```cs
          public class ViewModel2 : ViewModelBase
          {
               DemoHeader dd = new DemoHeader(1, "Document-1");
               dd.Items.Add(new DemoItem(1, 1, "Article 1", "A-1", 9999, "szt",ObjectType.article));
               dd.Items.Add(new DemoItem(1, 2, "Article 2", "A-2", 5999, "szt", ObjectType.article));

               this.Add(dd);

               WMSarticleItems = new ObservableCollection<DemoItem>() //initialize object
          }

            public DemoItem SelectedItem { get; set; } //remember to make it public :)


            public ObservableCollection<DemoItem> WMSarticleItems //second listbox container remeber that it must be property with get; set; to propely binding
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

    //rest code
```

Comment: What are your listboxes bound to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MVVM you should have a property in your view model containing the selected DemoItem in the list. This property should be bound to the listbox "SelectedItem" property.

When moving items it should be done using the view model properties, not the items in the view. When the item is moved you should update the view with OnPropertyChanged calls to the list, or even better your list should be ObservableCollections so they automatically updates the user interface when updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 ObservableCollections in your ViewModel databound to your 2 ListBoxes.
You need your Run Command and you also need a SelectedItem VM property that is TwoWay databound to the SelectedItem of the first ListBox. Inside your Run method you would get the SelectedItem and add it to the ObservableCollection of the second ListBox